# Is Unity (and Unity Web Player) dead?

Tags: unity

I know that Chrome stopped supporting UWP a long time ago, but I recently tried to play a Unity game and I just couldn't. I tried all the browsers, even IE which UWP itself suggests, however I couldn't run it on any platform?

Can anyone play Unity games anymore, or are they all useless now?

Thanks,

Comment: Yeah, Unity is dead for sure : https://unity3d.com/public-relations

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, Unity is certainly not dead :) But the Web Player [got deprecated](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/10/08/unity-web-player-roadmap/) in late 2015 after [NPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) support was dropped by most browsers.

It's still possible to develop for browsers in Unity by switching the target platform to HTML5/WebGL in the **Build Settings**. In contrast to the Web Player, HTML builds utilize standard APIs such as [WebGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL), [asm.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asm.js) etc. which allow you to run your application without installing any browser plugins.

- Here's some info about [how to build for WebGL](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-building.html)
- Another [getting started](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-gettingstarted.html) document which also mentions some limitations you have when building for WebGL
- And [here's a demo](http://webassembly.org/demo/) how Unity looks like using WebGL